# integration bankid api with php language

Tags: php, ssl, self-signed, bankid

i tried to integrate bankID with my code but it does not work

this is the tutorial [bankID tutorial](https://www.bankid.com/assets/bankid/rp/bankid-relying-party-guidelines-v2.15.)
this api have ssl certification  https://www.bankid.com/assets/bankid/rp/FPTestcert2_20150818_102329.pfx

can any one help me to integrate this api with php

this is my code

`try {
    $client = new SoapClient( 'https://appapi.test.bankid.com/rp/v4?wsdl', array( "local_cert" => "/certname.pem" ) );
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo  json_encode( array( "result" => false, "reason" => $e->getMessage() ) );}`

and because the ssl is pfx i convert it by useing openssl as

```
openssl pkcs12 -in FPTestcert2_20150818_102329.pfx -nocerts -out key.pem -nodes
```

openssl pkcs12 -in FPTestcert2_20150818_102329.pfx -nokeys -out cert.pem
openssl rsa -in key.pem -out server.key

```
Copy 
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
... 
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
section from server.key and
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
section from cert.pem and put them into new certname.pem file.
```

and this is the error 
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'link' : failed to load external entity

Comment: What about your code doesn't work? Share some code and the error message

Comment: Put it in the question and add your error message